# XamDateTimeEditor (Infragistics) mask is not visible when control is disabled or enabled(not in focus)

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate, infragistics

I have posted this in Infragistics, but just wondering if anyone overhere knows an answer.

How can I style the control, XamDateTimeEditor so that it will always shows mask whether the control is disabled or enabled(not in focus), so users can see what data is expected in that control always.

For example if the masket is set to hh:mm, and the control is enabled and in focus, it will display _ _ : _ _   I need this to visiable always irrespective, control is enabled or in focus.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the [DisplayMode](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WPF/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.Editors.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.Editors.XamMaskedEditor~DisplayMode.html) to IncludeBoth.

Comment: This setting is to display after you enter the text, if the text is empty, it will not display any masking characters

Comment: Well a couple of other options might be to force it to be in edit mode - e.g. set the IsAlwaysInEditMode to true. Or set the NullText to a string based on the mask being used (this will only help if nothing has been entered).